# How to handle errors in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and this time i would like to practice error handling in Python.
This is my exercise: 
I am having 2 lists:  `l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` si `l2 = [0, 1, ‘0’, ‘2’, ‘john’, 4]`. And I would like to iterate through l1 and for each index i want its element to be divided by the element on the same index in l2. If i am having an error, i would like to print the elements from each list as well as the index.

I am doing something wrong. Could you help me? 
Please find my code below:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = [0, 1, '0', '2', 'john', 4]

try:
    x=0
    float(x)
    for indexl1, elementl1 in enumerate(l1):
        for indexl2, elementl2 in enumerate(l2):
            x = elementl1 / elementl2
            print('-------')
except ValueError as ve:
    print('error, not number', elementl1, elementl2, indexl1, ve)
except ZeroDivisionError as zde:
    print('error, zerodiv', elementl1, elementl2, indexl1, zde)
else:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the error you are having.

Comment: When I ran this code it ran just as I would've expected: I got `error, zerodiv 1 0 0 division by zero` because the very first iteration path encountered that ZeroDivisionError and the error handling exited the loop.

Comment: You want the error handling to take place in the loop as the error causes it to break from the loop (so you are not making it past the first item).

Comment: I would like to show the error and move to the next iteration. I think this is were i got blocked

Comment: @Edelovic You can move the try-except inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to move the try except inside the inner loop:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = [0, 1, '0', '2', 'john', 4]

for indexl1, elementl1 in enumerate(l1):
    for indexl2, elementl2 in enumerate(l2):
        try:
            x = elementl1 / elementl2
            print('-------')
        except ValueError as ve:
            print('error, not number', elementl1, elementl2, indexl1, ve)
        except ZeroDivisionError as zde:
            print('error, zerodiv', elementl1, elementl2, indexl1, zde)
        else:
            print(x)
```